# Pergunta que pede mais esclarecimentos que outra

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-duplicadas

Na pergunta ["O que é Protótipo Javascript?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/215) o autor diz que já leu a pergunta ["Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/215) e suas respostas mas que continua sem entender. Não me pareceu haver nada de novo na pergunta que justificasse *não* fechá-la como duplicata.

Acabei respondendo a nova pergunta, com base na **experiência prévia** do autor:

> eu só sei JS até agora, to aprendendo.

Contraste com o tom da pergunta antiga:

> Entretanto, este não parece um conceito tão simples de entender para quem vem de outras linguagens.

Ou seja, minha resposta focou muito mais nos *fundamentos* que muitos programadores experientes já têm enraizados em suas mentes (em especial porque a maioria de nós teve alguma experiência com OO clássica antes de aprender JavaScript) do que nas especificidades do JavaScript. Coisa que a resposta à pergunta original já cobria muito bem e que - por não ter que explicar coisas supostamente "de conhecimento comum" - pôde ser muito mais sucinta e focada.

Entretanto, fiquei na dúvida: teria sido melhor se eu tivesse votado pra fechar a pergunta como duplicata e dado minha resposta *na pergunta original*? Será que dispersei conteúdo ao responder a uma pergunta diferente, quando ambas poderiam ser mescladas? Ou podem duas ou mais perguntas "serem diferentes" simplesmente porque o *background* do autor é diferente (e portanto demandam uma resposta diferente)?

Answer (score 5):

Analisando os títulos das perguntas, sem observar o seu conteúdo, parece-me que estão a ser tratados dois assuntos que apesar de semelhantes e que de alguma forma possam ser respondidos de uma só vez, são mais bem abordados se lidados separadamente:

- O que é Protótipo Javascript?

  Procura saber o que é X, cuja resposta ideal focaria uma abordagem sobre a história do X e o porque da sua existência.
- Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?

  Procura saber como funciona o X, cuja resposta ideal abordaria exemplos práticos de utilização do X em diversos ambientes.

Em separado, as respostas ficam mais organizadas e de alguma forma mais elaboradas.

**Por outro lado**, é do meu entendimento que todos nós, alguns de nós, ou só eu, não sabemos como algo funciona porque não sabemos o que esse algo é!

Pensando desta forma, a pergunta "O que é Protótipo Javascript?" para ter uma resposta completa carece de pelo menos um exemplo de utilização, dado este ser um site prático que procura abordar problemas e lidar com os mesmos de forma adequada.

**Tendo dito isto**, atendendo a ordem de eventos em que a parte técnica foi abordada antes da parte teórica, na minha opinião, **a forma como reagiste foi a mais correta**.

A pergunta "Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?" foi colocada primeiro, aborda a parte técnica/pratica e tem uma resposta aceite que clarificou o OP.

Ao aparecer uma pergunta "O que é Protótipo Javascript?", a resposta tem que ser dada com grande componente teórica e histórica podendo fazer referência à resposta prática já existente para dar a conhecer aos leitores que existe já onde podem aprender "Como funciona".

Responder na primeira pergunta com a componente teórica por si só não seria suficiente para ser uma resposta a lidar com o assunto em mãos, o que nos levaria a complementar a resposta com a componente prática, onde estaríamos quase que a obrigar o autor da resposta existente a melhorar a dele, quando na realidade a dele resolver em pleno o problema em mãos.

---

### Para futura referência

<sup>Na minha opinião:</sup>

Para futura referência, penso ser útil deixar a dica que ao responder a perguntas do género "Como funciona X?", o ideal e mais proveitoso para todos será começar as respostas com um pouco de história ou teoria sobre o X.

Desta forma, estamos a abrir um precedente para futuras respostas virem trazer mais informação ou maior elaboração sobre X.

De notar que uma pergunta "Como funciona X?" será mais interessante se elaborada "O que é e como funciona X?".

Existe também uma forma de pedir mais informação a uma pergunta do género "Como funciona X?", que é através da aplicação de uma recompensa:

> **Melhorar os detalhes**
>   As respostas atuais não contêm detalhes suficientes.

E podemos depois aplicar um texto personalizado pedindo respostas que abordem um pouco mais da componente teórica de X.

[image: Captura de tela]

Comment: Sua resposta me deixou com mais dúvidas do que quando li a pergunta! Mas estou achando que no futuro, após as duas perguntas esfriarem mais um pouco, elas podem sim ser mescladas, e a resultante editada para o formato *O que é e como funciona X?* Acho uma solução elegante, mas não me sinto confortável em fazer isso ainda, principalmente porque o autor da segunda pergunta ainda tem dúvidas sobre o assunto.

Comment: @bfavaretto Este tópico de facto pode ser abordado de diferente maneiras, tentei salientar cada uma delas... À data de hoje, e dada a sequência de eventos, efetivamente a forma de agir que foi empregue parece-me a mais correta. No futuro, só analisando as repostas existentes é que poderei opinar sobre a fusão das duas perguntas.

Comment: Ainda bem que ninguém perguntou "[o que é, para que serve e como funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4042/215) os protótipos", senão ia ser impossível dar uma resposta completa... De fato, num caso desses é melhor que existam perguntas separadas mesmo.